# Is it possible to use Ionic In App Purchase React js

Tags: ios, reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

So I am trying to implement In App Purchase using Ionic,my project is created using React JS, but I can't find any example using react js.

I found this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2 but it looks like it's only available for angular.

My question is: Is it possible to implement In App Purchase with Ionic and React js? Has someone done it already?

Comment: check this link "https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/community#react"